# How to release a UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I used several UIStoryboard in my app, but I found that when I changed the storyboard, the old did not released ,how to release the old one? the following is the code:

```
if([ModuleTeacher isEqualToString:type]){
    [self loginStateChanged];

    if([TeacherProfile getCurrentTeacher]!=nil){
        [self startPull];
    }
}else if([ModuleStudent isEqualToString:type]){
    UIStoryboard *main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StudentMain" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = [main instantiateInitialViewController];

    if([StudentProfile getCurrent]!=nil){
        [self startPull];
    }
}else if([ModuleOrgnization isEqualToString:type]){
    UIStoryboard *main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"OrganizeMain" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = [main instantiateInitialViewController];
    [AppCache setModule:type];
}
```

this way the old storyboard will be never released.

Comment: How do you know it didn't release?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use ARC.
2. If you have any strong references to the storyboard that you no longer need, set them to nil.
3. There is no step 3.

ARC will ensure that you release any references that are no longer needed. Making sure that your strong references are cleared when not needed lets ARC do the right thing. If your code isn't responsible for retaining the storyboard, you're not responsible for releasing anything. The Cocoa Touch framework may hang onto the storyboard for its own reasons -- this isn't your problem.

Comment: thanks at first. I used ARC, and I did set all strong variable to nil, but I switched on multiple storyboard, we found the old storyboard not released because dealloc is not being called

Comment: My point is that something in the framework may be holding onto the storyboard, perhaps caching it to improve performance or whatever. As long as you know that you're not keeping an unneeded strong reference to a storyboard you shouldn't worry about whether the storyboard is being deallocated.

Comment: When I used the "clear color" on my UIVviewController bgColor, I can see it.  And I think maybe some old code that it used viewDidUnload to release handle, but ios5 later it has been ...